# Large number of spurious retransmission - is my server under attack

Tags: wireshark, tcp

Please take a look at this picture, can anybody tell me are those packets sent from some kind of malware?

It is the same source IP address, different port numbers, SEQ number is always 0, and there are a lot of those packets...

[image]

Comment: You might get better responses if you provide the details in text form, rather than as a screenshot - makes the barrier to answering a lot lower. However, even then, it would be better to give some more details about the setup. Is the server yours, or a shared one? Is it running on AWS or similar service? Or is it an internal server at a company, on a local network? Where is the data you've shown from? We don't know your setup, but these details are important to work out what the issue could be.

Comment: It is a company Windows Server 2008, on VMWare. IT is in company VPN network. I am not a network expert, I am just trying to see why there is a high CPU on this server, and there are a lot connections generated on company's main router, and I suspect it is from this server receiving a lot of traffic.

Comment: I can't tell you this is not some form of attack, but I have seen this behavior as a result of flaky core switch.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, a packet capture won't tell you anything about a malicious payload. I suppose if you work with malware enough, you can see a pattern for particular malware byte code, but probably not.

Network analysis should be done based on a baseline. That's when red flags are apparent. If you've never done a base line before, it's hard to tell what is normal and what is worth investigating.

**Spurious Re-transmission**

This [blog](https://blog.packet-foo.com/2013/06/spurious-retransmissions/) gives a good rundown, and since I don't need to re-write the definition, from the blog:

> Basically “Spurious Retransmission” means that data was sent again
>   that the receiver had already acknowledged, which is something that we
>   used to call “needless retransmission” in our own expert system.

At this point, this question is not really for Information Security. It's damn near impossible for anyone here to give you security answer about a system they cannot directly analyze.

That being said, I would suggest you up date you question to trying figure out what's causing the Spurious Re-transmission, rather than thinking it's something else.

Here's a reference link to ask [wireshark](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/39808/malformed-packet-spurious-retransmissions-duplicate-and-rst) which may be of use. I'd move this to the networking or wireshark community.